# Invoke a Google Cloud function from another

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I would like to type in my Google Cloud function:

```
from my_google_cloud_project import another_google_cloud_func

another_google_cloud_func()
```

I don't want to invoke that function via HTTP request. How can I just import it?

Both functions are Google Cloud functions, but not just python code!

Comment: Is that function also deployed as well? e.g., does it actually take a `request` parameter?

Comment: Dustin Ingram It's deployed, but the trigger is not an http request

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `code.py` file and write your code there

read the content of that file

```py
with open('code.py') as f
    content = f.read()
```

then execute those content using

```py
exec(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the official documentation regarding :
[Packaging local dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python)

> You can also package and deploy dependencies alongside your function.
> This approach is useful if your dependency is not available via the
> pip package manager or if your Cloud Functions environment's internet
> access is restricted. For example, you might use a directory structure
> such as the following:
> [image]
> You can then use code as usual from the included local dependency, localpackage. You can use this approach to bundle
> any Python packages with your deployment.

Comment: The function I want to import is another Google Cloud function, it's not just inside .py file in the same parent directory.

Comment: From my understanding you can not import it. You have to call it over HTPPS.